# Is it possible to nullify parent inside a GraphQL Resolver?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, prisma, nexus-js

While optimizing my GraphQL resolvers, I have realized that resolving all the fields using their resolvers(not using the parent resolvers with some pre-filled data) is the way to utilize DataLoader in the most powerful way. Like this:

```ts
export const User = objectType({
  name: 'User',
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.id('id')
    t.string('email', {
      resolve(parent, _, ctx) {
        // `getUser()` is a function that fetches the DB and then returns Promise<User>
        // It's internally using Prisma, which has an internal DataLoader
        return getUser(ctx).then(user => user?.email)
      }
    })
    // more fields with similar resolvers...
  }
})
```

However, by doing this, it became impossible(at least in my knowledge) to return `null` user when the user doesn't exist. So the question came up.

1. Is it possible to nullify the entire parent object inside a GraphQL resolver?
2. If so, How?
3. If not, would adding something like `exists` field be the best solution for this?

Comment: **type resolver** should throw an error ( https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#throwing-errors ) BEFORE **fields resolvers**

Comment: @xadm I don't get what you're saying. I haven't mentioned anything about type resolvers in the question